# Excel DSTDEV without using headers in range

Tags: excel

Columns A & B contain a sample of data, with `shop` being an identifier (only two shown here)

I've setup two ranges in columns D & E which I can use the DSTDEV() function in column G

e.g. G2 formula is `=DSTDEV($A$1:$B$9,2,D1:E2)`
and  G4 formula is `=DSTDEV($A$1:$B$9,2,D4:E5)`

so the output currently is:

[image: ExampleData]

But in reality I have a tonne of `shop` identifiers so I wanted to be able to use the `DSTDEV()` as a flood-fill formula, ideally with an output like so:

[image: ExampleTarget]

Where I could calculate the standard deviation in column E for each `shop` in column D

I basically wanted `DSTDEV()` to work like `SUMIF()` but the criteria has to be a range, and I'm looking for a way round that?!

I thought I would ask before I go creating a UDF to do what I needed!

I tried supplying a split range in the format e.g. `(E1,E3)` as the criteria but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

An option would be using Pivot Tables:

[Subtotal and total fields in a PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/subtotal-and-total-fields-in-a-pivottable-173f5b30-b546-4293-87d2-aee638f74e7d?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

**StDev**: *An estimate of the standard deviation of a population, where the sample is a subset of the entire population.*

[image]

This will return exactly the result you want, besides it's really easy to manage and setup

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be use of the `STDEV.P` function integrated with `FILTER`. This relies on two premises:

1. `STDEV.P` calculates the population standard deviation based upon a list of values
2. `FILTER` can generate a dynamic array of values based on a single criteria when compared against a query list

So a `FILTER` array would look like this:

[image: Example of FILTER array based on unique line-item criteria]

Now that the list of individual values have been generated, this can simply be wrapped with the `STDEV.P` (or any other function based on lists) like this:

[image: Example of STDEV.P with dynamic FILTER dataset]

From there, you can anchor all elements except for the bold cell, and then flood fill accordingly:

```
=STDEV.P(FILTER(B2:B9,A2:A9=**D2**,))
```

[image: Final data]

Alternatively, it may be useful to include headers and named dynamic ranges via PivotTable, and you could avoid anchoring the formula.